# Java de parser with multi-character as quote or support of string delimiter

Tags: java, csv, parsing, delimiter, polybase

Is there any Java open source library that supports quoting string via multi-character (i.e., String with length > 1)  for delimited file?

Most of the delimited/CSV Parser support a single character as quote character (like " or ' ). But there is a requirement to read a delimited file by passing multi-character to a quote char. Or we can call it as string surroundings or string delimiter.
One of the use case is, in Azure we can bring data from `Azure Synapse Analytics` to `Gen2` via `Poly base SQLs`. In that we can provide only two options as file format, which is `FIELD_TERMINATOR` (field delimiter) and `STRING_DELIMITER` (quote character). They won’t escape any data while writing into `Gen2`.

If you data in DW is

---

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1   Anneke  Preusig
2   Georgi  Facello
```

---

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT file.CSV
WITH (FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,
      FORMAT_OPTIONS(
          FIELD_TERMINATOR = ',',
          STRING_DELIMITER = '|XYZ|',
);
```

File looks like

```
1,|XYZ|Anneke|XYZ|,|XYZ|Preusig|XYZ|
2,|XYZ|Georgi|XYZ|,|XYZ|Facello|XYZ|
```

So I am looking for a generic java library to read this file. Source data have all kind of data/characters so it is hard to identify a single character as quote character and there is no escaping happening while write such files.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Java Streams API the following might work if you're able to ensure that the `FIELD_TERMINATOR` is not used in either the `STRING_DELIMITER`or any of your values.

```
Path source = Paths.get("Your File");
char terminator = ',';
String delimiter = "|XYZ|";
String[][] parsed = Files.lines(source).map(l->
  Stream.of(l.split(""+terminator)).map(s->
    s.matches(delimiter+".*"+delimiter)?s.substring(delimiter.length(),s.length()-delimiter.length()):s
  ).toArray(String[]::new)
).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

This solution splits each line into its Fields and checks wether any given value is surrounded by your delimiter and removes it accordingly.

Edit:

For multiline data I wrote a little class, which decides based on a `Predicate<String[]>` wether a row of data is completed.

```
package com.example.parser;

import java.util.stream.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class FileIterator implements Iterator<String> {

  private String terminator;

  private Predicate<String[]> complete;

  private Iterator<String> source;

  private String[] buffer;
  private int pointer;

  public FileIterator(Iterator<String> source, String terminator, Predicate<String[]> complete) {
    this.source = source;
    this.terminator = terminator;
    this.complete = complete;
  }

  public static FileIterator from(Path path, String terminator, Predicate<String[]> complete) throws IOException {
    return new FileIterator(Files.lines(path).iterator(),terminator,complete);
  }

  public Stream<String> asStream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(this, Spliterator.DISTINCT), false);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return source.hasNext() || pointer < len(buffer);
  }

  @Override
  public String next() {
    if(pointer < len(buffer)) {
      return buffer[pointer++];
    } else {
      buffer = source.next().split(terminator);
      while(!complete.test(buffer)) {
        buffer = concat(buffer,source.next().split(terminator));
      }
      pointer = 1;
      return buffer[0];
    }
  }

  private static String[] concat(String[] b1, String[] b2) {
    if(b1 == null) return b2;
    if(b2 == null) return b1;
    String[] r = new String[b1.length+b2.length-1];
    for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
      if(i < b1.length-1) r[i] = b1[i];
      else if(i == b1.length-1) r[i] = b1[i] + '\n' + b2[0];
      else r[i] = b2[i-b1.length+1];
    }
    return r;
  }

  private static int len(String[] b) {
    return b == null ? 0 : b.length;
  }

}
```

The `next()` method works by building a buffer of the elements of the current row by repeatetly asking the Predicate wether it is finished or not and then emptying it in the successive calls. The intendet use case is as follows:

```
FileIterator.from(Paths.get("yourFile"),",",(s)->yourWayOfDeterminingWetherARowIsTerminated(s)).asStream();
```

Elements that got split up by a new line also get rejoined with the \n character. However, this method does not remove the string quotes, but that can be done in a similar fashion like above. Also the elements are returned solo, but the implementation could be changed to return the whole buffer to match the above example. To test wether your row is terminated I suggest looking at a regex that identifies your unfinished address.

```
  @Override
  public String[] next() {
    String[] buffer = source.next().split(terminator);
    while(!complete.test(buffer)) {
      buffer = concat(buffer,source.next().split(terminator));
    }
    return buffer;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It was helpful, but challenge is now with new line in data. If we have column with multi line data (like address) it won't work.

Comment: @ShrikrishnaBhat I dont know how your addresses are formatted, but i hope the edit helps

Comment: Thank you Severin Nitsche for all the help here and leads. Will take it from here and what best can be done